Coordinate representation of basis element of tangent space with respect to a normal coordinate
It seems easy question but I don't prove rigorously until now.
Q. Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian or pseudo-Riemannian manifold of dimension $n$ ( without boundary ).
Let $(w_1, \dots , w_n)$ be an orthonormal basis for $T_pM$. Consider a normal coordinate chart
$\varphi : U \to \hat{U} \subseteq\mathbb{R}^n := B^{-1}|_V^{\hat{U}} \circ (\operatorname{exp}_p|_V)^{-1}$ centered at $p$, where $B: \mathbb{R}^n \to T_p M$ ; $ (x^1 , \dots , x^n) \mapsto x^1 w_1 + \cdots + x^nw_n$ and $\operatorname{exp}_p : V \to U$ is a diffeomorphism. And $\hat{U}:=B^{-1}(V)$. Let $\partial / \partial x^i|_p$ , $ 1 \le i \le n$ be the coordinate vectors at $p$ associated with the $(U,\varphi)$.
Then my question is, $w_i = \partial/\partial x^i|_p$ for all $1\le i \le n$? If so, why? A priori, it seems reasonable but how can we show..
Note that $\partial/\partial x^i |_p :=d (\varphi^{-1})_{\varphi(p)} ( \partial/\partial x^i)|_{\varphi(p)})= d (\varphi^{-1})_{0} ( \partial/\partial x^i)|_{0}) $. I considered to try to show that for each $f\in C^{\infty}(M)$, $w_i(f) = (\partial/\partial x^i|_p)(f)$. But
$$(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}|_p)(f) = ( \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}|_{0}) (f  \circ \varphi^{-1}) = \frac{\partial ( f \circ ( \operatorname{exp} |_V^U \circ B|_{\hat{U}}^V))}{\partial x^i} (0) \stackrel{?}{=} w_i (f). $$
And final equality is true? I also considered to apply the chain rule and don't know how to make progress further. Or perhaps is there any other simple route by observing some point? Can anyone help?

Note that $$(d\varphi_p)^{-1}= d(\varphi^{-1})_{\varphi(p)}=d(\varphi^{-1})_0 = d ( \operatorname{exp}_p|_{V}^U \circ B|_{\hat{U}}^V)_0 =\\ d((\operatorname{exp}_p)|_V^{U})_{B(0)} \circ d(B|_{\hat{U}}^V)_0 = \\
d((\operatorname{exp}_p)|_V^{U})_{0} \circ d(B|_{\hat{U}}^V)_0. \tag{1}$$
Note that $d((\operatorname{exp}_p)|_V^{U})_{0}$ is identity map of $T_pM$, under the usual identification of $T_0(T_pM)$ with $T_p M$ ( $\because$ John Lee's Introduction to Riemannian manifolds, Proposition 5.19-(d) ). And $d(B|_{\hat{U}}^V)_0$ can be viewed as $B$ upto suitable isomorphisms since $B$ is linear transformation ($\because$ John Lee's Introduction to smooth manifolds, Proposition 3.13 ).
So $$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x ^i}|_p := (d \varphi_p)^{-1}(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}|_{\varphi(p)}) \stackrel{(1)}{=} B(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}|_{0}):=w_i  $$
